# How to display rendered event in fullcalendar when click

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

The calendar events are working and rendered correctly based on their corresponding dates, however I want to click on a particular date and display the event. Here is my code

```
 handleDateClick($event) {
let DateStart = this.convertDate($event.view.currentStart);
let DateEnd = this.convertDate($event.view.currentEnd);
this.TradePerformanceServ.getCalendarTradePerformance(this.user, DateStart, DateEnd).then(res => {
  this.calendarEvents = res.performance;
  for (var i = 0;i < res.performance.length;i++){
    console.log('Amount: ', res.performance[i].title);
  }

  console.log('Server response  ', this.calendarEvents);

  const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ModalCalendarGainLossComponent, {
    maxWidth: '100vw',
    width: '300px',
    maxHeight: '100vh',
    data: {
      amount: res.performance[0].title,
      date: $event.dateStr
    }
  });
})};
```

I want to pass the event in data { amount: 'insert_amount_value' } parameter. As of now when I click on a particular date, it prints all the event value.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "click on a particular date and display the event" ...doesn't entirely make sense. A specific date could easily contain multiple events, or none. FullCalendar already provides a way for you to handle when a user clicks on a specific event (as opposed to a date), though: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventClick . That gives you access to information about the event which was clicked. Does that help you?

Comment: However if you want to click on a particular date and then display all the events which occur on that date, you can do so, but you will need to filter the `calendarEvents` list yourself by looking at the start/end date of each event, compared with the date of the clicked event. fullCalendar doesn't provide a built-in method to output that information.